# Multiple heatmaps at once

Tags: r, heatmap, facet-wrap, geom-tile

I am trying to get multiple heatmaps using facet_wrap and geom_tile function, I have 1000 samples.

My objective is to obtain a heatmap for each Parent_Gene that include the "Condition" in the “X” axis, "response value" as a “fill” and the Genes belonging to the same Parent_Gene in the “Y” axis.

| ID | sl | condition | Gene | Response_Value | Parent_Gene |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | S1 | disease1 | GeneKPN1 | 2.749526 | GeneKPN |
| 2 | S2 | disease2 | GeneKPN2 | 6.606618 | GeneKPN |
| 3 | S3 | disease1 | GeneBKJH1 | 4.697644 | GeneBKJH |

Here is my script so far. My issue is that I just want the genes belonging to the corresponding parent_gene depicted in each heatmap and not all the genes every time.

```
my_data <- read.csv("my_data.csv")

my_data$Parent_Gene <- gsub("([A-Z)]+)\\d+.*","\\1", my_data $Gene)

library(tidyverse)

 gg<- ggplot(my_data, aes(x=Condition, y=Gene, fill= Response_Value))+
  geom_tile(color="white", size=0.1)+
 scale_fill_viridis(name="response levels")

 gg + coord_equal()

gg + facet_wrap(~Parent_Gene, ncol=2)

gg <- gg + labs(x=NULL, y=NULL, title="Comparative response levels")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `scales = "free"` to your `facet_wrap()`. This will "free" up the scales, which in your case will leave only the included genes in your plot. You can also specify to free up individual scales, e.g. using `free_x` or `free_y`, which can be useful if you want to have different genes on the x-axis, but retain the scale of the y-axis.

These are also detailed in the help page, which you can access using `?facet_wrap`.